# Scrollable CustomMultiChildLayout

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I can't get CustomMultiChildLayout to be scrollable.

For now my CustomMultiChildLayout just laying out children in a column. In a future I'll make it more complex, but now I want to make it scrollable. I tried putting it inside `ListView`, but got `RenderIndexedSemantics object was given an infinite size during layout.`.
I tried putting it inside `SingleChildScrollView` with `IntrinsicHeight` but in this case it can't be scrolled and it's height is the same as viewport.

Here is some examples that is not working properly:

```dart
return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: IntrinsicHeight(
          child: CustomMultiChildLayout(
            delegate: ViewLayoutBuilder(itemCount: cards.length),
            children: _buildChildren(context),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

and

```
return ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          CustomMultiChildLayout(
            delegate: ViewLayoutBuilder(itemCount: cards.length),
            children: _buildChildren(context),
          )
        ],
      )
```

Here is my `ViewLayoutBuilder` delegate:

```
class ViewLayoutBuilder extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  final int itemCount;

  ViewLayoutBuilder({@required this.itemCount});

  @override
  void performLayout(Size size) {
    Offset position = Offset(0,0);
    Size firstSize = layoutChild('card_0', BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: size.width));
    positionChild('card_0', position);
    position = position.translate(0, firstSize.height);
    for (int i = 1; i < itemCount; i++) {
      final String cardId = 'card_$i';

      if (hasChild(cardId)) {
        Size newSize = layoutChild('$cardId', BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: size.width));
        positionChild('$cardId', position);
        position = position.translate(0, newSize.height);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(MultiChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

The main error in all my tries is that my `CustomMultiChildLayout` given an infinity height. In other cases it is cropped to a viewport height and can't be scrolled.

Comment: For multichild why don't you try `ListView.builder` ?

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky I'm actually building multi-column layout where children distributed by columns evenly depends on its size. I tried a lot of different layout builders and looks like `CustomMultiChildLayout` is the only way to do this.

Comment: any success with that one?

Comment: Hi @Arek. I ended up implementing my own `MultiChildRenderObjectWidget`. You can find it in the [code of my app](https://github.com/estevez-dev/ha_client/blob/master/lib/plugins/dynamic_multi_column_layout.dart).